# Suppressing blank lines between descriptions in ConTeXt

Tags: lists, context

EDIT I changed the title to make this post easier to find for someone not too familiar with ConTeXt syntax. Previous title was "Is there a joinedup equivalent for \setupdescriptions?"

Which option should I set to get the same effect for descriptions as when using `joinedup` in `setupitemize` (no blank line between entries)? I couldn't find it in the ConTeXt ref, nor in the wiki. What did I miss?

Here is a MWE

```
\definedescription[Test]%[joinedup]
\starttext
Let's test!

\Test{Hello} world!\par
\Test{Bonjour} tout le monde\par
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no simple option for `\setupdescription` to disable the vertical space between consecutive description because there is no communication between the entries.

What you can do this disable all `\blank` commands for a limited region is to put a `packed` environment around the content. As a result of this you disabled also the vertical space before the first and after the last entry, to get it back you have to add extra `\blank` commands at these points.

```
\blank
\startpacked
...
\stoppacked
\blank
```

To keep the extra commands in your document to a minimum you can create a new environment with `\definestartstop` which adds \blank before and after the `packed` block.

```
\definedescription [Test]

\definestartstop
  [packeddescription]
  [before=\blank\startpacked,
   after=\stoppacked\blank]

\starttext

Let's test!

\startpackeddescription

\startTest {Hello}
  world!
\stopTest

\startTest {Bonjour}
  tout le monde
\stopTest

\stoppackeddescription

\stoptext
```

[image]